# How to get a field value from a Document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have learned how to create and update documents in a firebase firestore cloud, however I am having trouble reading data. Attached is my code for finding the value of the 'photourl' field:

```
String photoy; 
Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document('sepDGexTRuRkpx1WQYylDDmUI573')
.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds){
          photoy=ds.data['photourl'];      
});

  setState(() {
              photourldisplay=photoy;
             });
```

However, upon running my program, the photourldisplay value seems to not have changed and remains null upon running. This means that something is askew with my code that retrieves this "photourl" field. Can someone help me retrieve a field in a firebase document? 
[image: Firebase Documents]
[image: Firebase security rules]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of code.  Copy the text of the code into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  Since you're showing security rules, you might also want to show the client code that would be impacted by the rules, as well as the result that you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good you just have to await for the result:

```
void yourVoid () async {
    String photoy;
    await Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document('sepDGexTRuRkpx1WQYylDDmUI573')
        .get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds){
      photoy=ds.data['photourl'];
    });

    setState(() {
      photourldisplay=photoy;
    });
  }
```

EDIT:
as @Doug Stevenson said, there is two propers solutions:

```
void yourVoid () async {


    DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document('sepDGexTRuRkpx1WQYylDDmUI573')
        .get();

    String photoy = ds.data['photourl'];

    setState(() {
      photourldisplay=photoy;
    });
  }
```

and:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document('sepDGexTRuRkpx1WQYylDDmUI573')
.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds){
    photoy=ds.data['photourl'];      

    setState(() {
        photourldisplay=photoy;
    });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: If you want to do it this way, there's no need for a `then` callback at all.  `await` will return the DocumentSnapshot directly for use on the next line.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes your answer is better, I did a quick answer.

Answer (score 5):

`photoy` does not contain the value you expect because Firestore queries are asynchronous.  The get() returns immediately, and the callback is invoked some time later, after the query completes.  There is no guarantee how long a query might take.  If you want to pass the value of `photoy` to something else, you will have to wait until the callback completes by making use of it only within that callback.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document('sepDGexTRuRkpx1WQYylDDmUI573')
.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds){
    photoy=ds.data['photourl'];      

    setState(() {
        photourldisplay=photoy;
    });   
});
```

Comment: Great explanation!