# How to get values of a field in Firestore in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I use a document in firestore that stores three fields with boolean values. This boolean values I need for further processsing. In my programm I want to read this values. But how to read the fields of a document? As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901979/how-to-get-a-field-value-from-a-document-in-firestore) it should work like following:

```js
const getStateEntries = async () => {
  await getDoc(doc(db, 'Collection_Name', 'Document_ID'))
  .then((docSnap)=> {
    let alertField = docSnap.data['alert_state']
    console.log(alertField)
  })
  setAlertState(alertField)
}
```

When I run the code it looks like get no access to the field. When I print the variable to the console, I get an `'undefined'`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get something like below code:

```
firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    console.log('Total users: ', querySnapshot.size);

    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
      console.log('User ID: ', documentSnapshot.id, documentSnapshot.data());
    });
  });
```

For reference use, this one: https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

The data is not a property on DocumentSnapshot. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
let alertField = docSnap.data().alert_state
```